# How can I get laravel's locale in javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, internationalization, translation

I'm creating an app in four languages and every url goes like this:

```
app.name/en/rest/of/the/url
app.name/de/rest/of/the/url
app.name/nl/rest/of/the/url
app.name/fr/rest/of/the/url
```

How can I get this in the javascript? I need to translate some strings, but I need the locale to know which lang to choose

Answer (score 12):

If you dont want to use PHP inside script tags. You can do like this

layout blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
Content of the document......

<script>
// Plain javascript
var locale = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");
// jQuery
var localeJquery = $('html').attr('lang');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For multi language sites use `<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">`

Answer (score 3):

find locate in laravel  by facade

```
$locate = App::getLocale()
```

by helper function

```
config('app.locale')
```

by JavaScript to add

```
<script>
 var locate = {!! config('app.locale') !!};
</script>
```

for more information about locate [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript just add

```
<script>
 var locale = '{{ config('app.locale') }}';
</script>
```

and you can used "locale" variable in JS file.

or you can check by

```
console.log(locale);
```